# Why does the title callback of /user produce the title for /user/register?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm a bit puzzled why the title callback of /user produces the title for /user/register and /user/password.

When I set the title callback of /user, I see this affects the title of /user/register and /user/password. However, setting a title callback for /user/register seems to make no difference; it appears to stick to the title callback of /user.

What is special about /user/register and /user/password which results in titles for these callbacks to have their titles produced by the title callback of /user?

```
function mytheme_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['user']['title callback'] = 'mytheme_user_title';
}

function mytheme_user_title($title) {
  return 'test';
}
```

Comment: Do you mean the title User account or the title of the tab e.g. Register for `user/register`?

Comment: I mean the page title. The `mytheme_user_title` for `user` generates the page title for `user/register` and `user/password`.

Comment: Does it have to be in theme?

Answer (score 0):

For the `user/register` title to be changed in a theme:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Only act when the first part of the url equals 'user', the second
  // part is 'register'
  $arg = arg();
  if ($arg[0] == 'user' && $arg[1] == 'register') {
    $variables['title'] = 'Test';
  }
}
```

For the `user/register` title to be changed in a module:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
  drupal_set_title(t('Test'));
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, but setting $variables['title'] doesn't truly change the title - it only changes the rendered title. And changing the title via form_alter results in the page title being changed even if I, say, embed that form in another page...

Comment: You lost me - what does "doesn't change the title but rendered title" mean?

Comment: When you set $variables['title'], that is only a title for the page theme file. Other parts of the site will keep using the 'real' title (browser bar title, metatag module etc etc).

Comment: You said `user/register`, I gave you such an example.

Comment: @sbrattla is saying that, using the code shown for `hook_preprocess_page()`. other modules would still think the page title is the one set in his `mytheme_user_title()`, since the title is changed right before the page is rendered.

Comment: The question is why the title is changed for different pages, which is not what the OP is expecting. Using a title callback from a theme is supported, as far as i recall.